# Is it possible to move VB.Net MDI child forms to another screen?

Tags: vb.net, mdichild, multiple-screens

10 years ago, I have developed an MDI application using VB.Net.

Since, I have also developed a Primefaces Java Oracle application with multiple tabs in Chrome and some possibilities to move some tabs on another screen.

I'm now interesting to use same technic for my VB.Net application.

Is it possible to dynamically move a MDI Child form from main application in a second screen ?

Is it possible using MDI child or must I migrate to SDI application ?

Comment: If you remove the MdiParent reference, you can. Otherwise, the Child Form only move inside its MDI Container. The MDI interface is quite *dated*.

Comment: @Jimi, thanks. But is there a new MDI interface WITH tabs as done in any modern browsers ?

Comment: Not a *formal* interface that replaces it. The use of Tabs in *modern* GUIs has quite different implementations. E.g. the custom TabControl that Visual Studio uses to organize its *documents* is completely different than the *Tabbed Interface* that Chrome or FireFox build. In WPF or WinForms, you can use the standard TabControl, with or without labels, to switch containers. To drag a TabPage outside its TabControl, you have to build a new Window container on-the-fly and re-parent the original container pane. Different producers of components have their own implementations.